# Cannot delete from view without exactly one key-preserved table workaround

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table x_visa. I want to delete the duplicate columns from this table.

The query I am using for this is :

```
  select * from   (SELECT x_visa.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by effective_start_date, effective_end_date, person_id,
                   business_group_id, legislation_code , current_visa_permit, visa_permit_type, visa_permit_id, configuration_id
               order by person_id) AS rn
        from   x_visa) T
WHERE  rn > 1 );
```

The delete statement is giving an error :ORA-01752: cannot delete from view without exactly one key-preserved table

```
delete from
(select * from   (SELECT x_visa.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by effective_start_date, effective_end_date, person_id,
                   business_group_id, legislation_code , current_visa_permit, visa_permit_type, visa_permit_id, configuration_id
               order by person_id) AS rn
        from   x_visa) T
WHERE  rn = 1 );
```

Is there a workaround to delete the duplicate data from this table ?

Answer (score 3):

Each row has `rowid` identifier. So you can delete where rowid in results of your query.

```
delete from x_visa where rowid in (/*YOUR QUERY*/);
```

So we have:

```
delete from x_visa where rowid in (select r from   (SELECT x_visa.rowid r, x_visa.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by effective_start_date, effective_end_date, person_id,
                   business_group_id, legislation_code , current_visa_permit, visa_permit_type, visa_permit_id, configuration_id
               order by person_id) AS rn
        from   x_visa) T
WHERE  rn > 1 ))
```